# Selenium IDE works, but Python Selenium doesn't: maybe iFrame issue

Tags: python, selenium, iframe, selenium-chromedriver

I have created code using the Chrome Selenium IDE extensions that works properly. I've created code that follows the same steps within Python. The problem is: when I run the Python code, it fails to find the element by ID that the Selenium IDE has no problem finding. The element is within an iFrame, so I account for this, and no errors are thrown when loading the iFrame.

[Here is the website where I'm trying to enter the codeword and email address.](https://alt949.radio.com/contest/holiday-feast-win-free-tickets)

Below is a side-by-side of both code sets.

### [image: side-by-side]

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument("--test-type")
#options.add_argument("--incognito")
options.binary_location = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Users\James\Documents\Scripts\lib\chromedriver.exe')
#driver.set_page_load_timeout(30)

actions = ActionChains(driver) 


driver.get('https://alt949.radio.com/contest/holiday-feast-win-free-tickets#//')
for _ in range(2):
    driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
time.sleep(10)

#Switch to iframe
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe"))

#Set keyword
keyword_input = driver.find_element_by_id('ember634')
keyword_input.send_keys('keyword')

driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the 'ember' ids can change over time (possibly being generated by distributed CMS) so a different approach to field identification is required. The below code will get you through the first screen reliably. Also as it is an interactive form I have switched to a Wait model rather then using a sleep timer.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# Set options to simplify flow and persist user data 
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
chrome_options.add_argument('start-maximized')
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', {'credentials_enable_service': False, 'profile': {'password_manager_enabled': False}})

print("Loading page")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
driver.get('https://alt949.radio.com/contest/holiday-feast-win-free-tickets#//')

print("Find frame")
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//iframe[@data-ss-embed='iframe']")))
driver.switch_to.frame(element)

print("Enter codeword")
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".ssRegistrationField.ssTextboxField.ember-text-field.ember-view")))
element.click()
element.send_keys('codeword')

print("Enter email")
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".ssRegistrationField.ssEmailTextboxField.ember-text-field.ember-view")))
element.click()
element.send_keys('myemail@gmail.com')

print("Click Continue")
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'ssButton')))
element.click()
```

Comment: Thanks, after tweaking a little bit, this works great! I didn't know about the WebDriverWait functionality and it looks like the ideal solution.